# Azure Kubernetes Service Creates Extra Resource Groups

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group, azure-aks

I have created an instance of Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) and have discovered that apart from the resource group I created the AKS instance in, two other resource groups were created for me. Here is what my resource groups and their contents looks like:

- `MyResourceGroup-Production`

  - `MyAKSInstance` - Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
- `DefaultResourceGroup-WEU`

  - `ContainerInsights(MyAKSInstance)` - Solution
  - `MyAKSInstance` - Log Analytics
- `MC_MyResourceGroup-Production_MyAKSInstance_westeurope`

  - `agentpool-availabilitySet-36219400` - Availability set
  - `aks-agentpool-36219400-0` - Virtual machine
  - `aks-agentpool-36219400-0_OsDisk_1_09469b24b1ff4526bcfd5d00840cfbbc` - Disk
  - `aks-agentpool-36219400-nic-0` - Network interface
  - `aks-agentpool-36219400-nsg` - Network security group
  - `aks-agentpool-36219400-routetable` - Route table
  - `aks-vnet-36219400` - Virtual network

I have a few questions about these two separate resource groups:

1. Can I rename the resource groups or control how they are named from my ARM template in the first place at the time of creation?
2. Can I move the contents of `DefaultResourceGroup-WEU` into `MyResourceGroup-Production`?
3. Can I safely edit their settings?
4. The `DefaultResourceGroup-WEU` seems to be created if you enable Log Analytics. Can I use this instance for accepting logs from other instances?

### UPDATE

I managed to pre-create a log analytics resource and use that for Kubernetes. However, there is a third resource that I'm having trouble moving into my resource group:

```
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "name": "SolutionDeployment",
        "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
        "resourceGroup": "[split(parameters('omsWorkspaceId'),'/')[4]]",
        "subscriptionId": "[split(parameters('omsWorkspaceId'),'/')[2]]",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "template": {
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "parameters": {},
                "variables": {},
                "resources": [
                    {
                        "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview",
                        "type": "Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions",
                        "location": "[parameters('workspaceRegion')]",
                        "name": "[concat('ContainerInsights', '(', split(parameters('omsWorkspaceId'),'/')[8], ')')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "workspaceResourceId": "[parameters('omsWorkspaceId')]"
                        },
                        "plan": {
                            "name": "[concat('ContainerInsights', '(', split(parameters('omsWorkspaceId'),'/')[8], ')')]",
                            "product": "[concat('OMSGallery/', 'ContainerInsights')]",
                            "promotionCode": "",
                            "publisher": "Microsoft"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": []
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, you cant.
2. Yes, but I'd advice against it. I'd advice remove the health metrics from AKS, delete that resource group, create OMS in the same resource group with AKS (or wherever you need your OMS to be) and then use that OMS. it will just create container solution for you in the same resource group where oms is in.
3. To extent, if you break anything AKS wont fix it
4. Yes you can, but you better rework it like I mention in point 2.

Comment: I can't seem to find a simple OMS ARM template, they all come with lots of resources built in. Also, is it recommended to create one Log Analytics for all environments (Test, Production etc.)?

Comment: Is it recommended practice to create one per environment?

Comment: i usually do that, but that is not necessary

Comment: There is a third "Solutions" resource that I'm having trouble creating and linking to Kubernetes. I can't see any documentation for it to see what it is or how I can create it.

Comment: Added the ARM template for the "Solutions" resource to the question.

Comment: you srsly need to raise a new question for this